# How do I select all including sensitive case (regex) in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, selectall

I have a problem with a regex command,

I have a file with a tons of lines and with a lot of sensitive characters,

```
this is an Example with all sensitive case 0123456789/*-+.&é"'(-è_çà)=~#{[|`\^@]}²$*ù^%µ£¨¤,;:!?./§<>AZERTYUIOPMLKJHGFDSQWXCVBNazertyuiopmlkjhgfdsqwxcvbn
```

I tried many regex commands but never get the expected result,
I have to select everything from **Example to the end**

---

I tried this command on https://www.regextester.com/ :

> \sExample(.*?)+

[Image of the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86fBM.png)

And when I tried it in **C#** the only result I get was : `Example`

I don't understand why --'

Comment: Using a greedy quantifier like `\sExample.*` would be preferable

Comment: I always recommend using [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) for testing Regex as it allows you to see the eact results and then get the equivalent C# code snippet to use in your app. I would start with what @CaiusJard suggested and try greedy.

Comment: Thanks a lot (I started using regex today I'm kinda newbie --')

Comment: if i am not mistaken /i is the regex for case insensitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick chat about greedy and pessimistic:

Here is test data:

```
Example word followed by another word and then more
```

Here are two regex:

```
Example.*word
Example.*?word
```

The first is greedy. Regex will match `Example` then it will take `.*` which consumes everything all the way to the END of the string and the works backwards spitting a character at a time back out, trying to make the match succeed. It will succeed when `Example word followed by another word` is matched, the .* having matched `word followed by another` (and the spaces at either end)

The second is pessimistic; it nibbled forwards along the string one character at a time, trying to match. Regex will match `Example` then it'll take one more character into the `.*?` wildcard, then check if it found `word` - which it did. So pessimistic matching will only find a single space and the full match in pessimistic mode is `Example word`

Because you say you want the whole string after Example I recommend use of a greedy quantifier so it just immediately takes the whole string that remains and declares a match, rather than nibbling forwards one at a time (slow)

This, then, will match (and capture) everything after Example:

```
\sExample(.*)
```

The brackets make a capture group. In c# we can name the group using `?<namehere>` at the start of the brackets and then everything that .* matches can be retrieved with:

```
Regex r = new Regex("\sExample(?<x>.*)");
Match m = r.Match("Exampleblahblah");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["x"].Value); //prints: blahblah
```

Note that if your data contains newlines you should note that . doesn't match a newline, unless you enable RegexOptions.SingleLine when you create the regex

[image]